# Javascript error - log:Net state changed from BUSY to CLIENT_ERROR

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

There is a log entry saying that there is an error on client side, however, the errors are not shown in Firebug.

Where can I see error details?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a logging framework that's eating your error? Or are you sure that CLIENT_ERROR means that an exception was thrown?

Comment: Yeah I don't think there is anything else to see. You must be using some framework or library that has written that log to the console. What library is that log coming from?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in an [internal error](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.ErrorType#gapi.drive.realtime.ErrorType.CLIENT_ERROR) generated by the google drive framework. It's not necessarily a critical error--the framework seems to discard the error.

Firebug does not show an indication of an error, because the message you're seeing is generated by the console.log function (i.e. it's not a javascript compilation error.)

If you could share the code, perhaps it would be easier to say how the error was generated.